# Perl not executing shell commands when run from cron

Tags: perl, cron

I have a Perl script which calls a PHP script from the command line and sends the output via e-mail. This script works fine when executed from the command line, but fails when executed via cron. I have tried executing the script from my own crontab, as well as the root cron, same result.

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $file = "/app/testing/testfile.php";
my $output = `php $file`;
#Sending e-mail here
```

And this is the PHP script that it is calling:

```
fopen('/app/testing/log.txt', 'w');
fwrite('hi');
echo 'hi';
```

When run from the command line, I get an e-mail with the word "hi" and the file has the word hi. Run from cron, I get a blank e-mail and the file is not modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide full path to `php`:

```
my $output = `/path/to/php $file`;
```

This is because `cron` uses a rather simplified environment, with a minimalistic `$PATH`.

Alternatively, source your `.*rc` file in `cron`, but that may be an overkill:

```
03 */1 * * * source ~/.zshrc &> /dev/null ; /path/to/my_script.pl
```